# Flex: preventDefault does not prevent char from being added

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I want to prevent characters from being added to a `TextInput` if the width of the text is greater than a specified amount. The first problem I am encountering is that `preventDefault` is not preventing any character from being added like I expected. Is there an explanation to this? How could I achieve what I want?

```
<s:TextInput id="textInput0"/>

protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    textInput0.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkWidthOfText, false, 0, true);
}
protected function checkWidthOfText(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

    event.preventDefault();     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `capture` event phase and `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT` event:

```
        protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            textInput0.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, checkWidthOfText, true, 0, true);
        }
        protected function checkWidthOfText(event:TextEvent):void{

            event.preventDefault();     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` will only work if the component you're trying to change the behaviour of actually implements some preventing mechanism. To be more concrete, the text field (I say text field because down the line the Flex TextInput uses the core Flash [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html)) in this case would have to do something like:

```
if (!keyDownEvt.isDefaultPrevented()) insertKey(keyDownEvt.charCode);
```

which it probably doesn't.

As for a solution to your problem: it can simply be achieved by using TextInput's `maxChars` property:

```
<s:TextInput maxChars="20"/>
```

Or did you really mean the physical width instead of the amount of characters?

Comment: yes, it's right, but as for flex _TextInput_ it doesn't use own input processing logic, it's only wrap the native _TextField_ with _type=input_ so you can operate with it as TextField in this case.